# Why do we struggle so much when we try to pronounce something correctly?

Tags: pronunciation, intonation

Being native speakers of English, You guys pronounce all the words exactly the way they should be pronounced effortlessly, no matter how fast you speak. We non-native speakers of English, however, struggle with every single word when we want to get the pronunciations and intonations right. Does that mean we're doing something wrong here? If we are pronouncing them right, how come it takes so much energy out of us while you guys don't seem to be struggling at all when you speak? Could it be that we are not doing it right? Or is this normal?

Comment: I am sure it works the other way around, too.  You pronounce your own language (which you learned as a child) flawlessly, but we (learning it as adults) cannot do that.

Comment: You might want to try this question, for better response, over at [languagelearning.SE]

Comment: The earlier in life you learn something, the easier it is. We speak from about age 1.

Comment: To be fair, I’d say that there a people who can’t pronounce their own native language fluently. (whatever the language).

Comment: Please review the objectives of this site as described in the Tour, and then consider carefully whether this question could conceivably be considered on topic here. I would think not.

Comment: Ask my wife -- I enjoy mispronouncing words!

Comment: I don't think it is fair to group all non-native English speakers together and say that they struggle with English pronunciation. I would suggest that this struggle may apply in the case of *new* English speakers, but certainly not all non-native speakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Being native speakers of English, You guys pronounce all the words
> exactly the way they should be pronounced effortlessly, no matter how
> fast you speak.

This is not always true. People who read widely sometimes have a larger vocabulary than their peers and so have never heard the word spoken correctly.

As an example, I once heard my now deceased father pronounce "placebo" as "place bo" instead of "pla see bo".

Given his great age at the time I didn't think it useful to correct him.

A common pronunciation error, especially in young readers is "misled".  The standard pronunciation of this is "miss led" whereas the mistaken version is something like "myzled".

Note how difficult it is for me to show pronunciations in the above paragraph. English spelling is insufficiently phonetic to achieve much success at this. There are more vowel sounds in English (especially southern British English) than there are  symbols (a, e, i, o, u) to represent them.

Note also that US, UK and other regional pronunciations differ for many words.

---

P.S. If you are familiar with IPA then, by using a suitable dictionary, you can learn conventional pronunciations.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects

Here is an IPA dictionary that also allows you to hear the words (in British English). https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ipa